# Same text alignment inside a parbox as the environment where it is

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, parbox

How `\parbox` could "inherit" the "alignment mode" used in the environment where it is called?
In other words, how can I automate the text alignment setting into a `\parbox`, in order to take the same text-alignment as the main paragraph?

I am thinking about three `if/then` sentences for left, right or center "modes", but I don't know how "get" the "current" value that latex is using at that point. I mean, something like that:

```
\begin{center}
Some text here
\if@... \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\centering Some text here}
\if@... \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedright ...}
\if@... \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft ...}
Some text here
\end{center}
```

I would like it works under both environments (`\begin{center}`...) and declarations (`\centering`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `\meaning` of the various (4) modes, one sees that the 2 lengths  `\parfillskip` and `\rightskip`, in combination, form a unique identifier for each mode.  Therefore, just use the expressions of these two lengths, saved in a string, to make the identification by way of `\ifx` comparison.

I then introduce `\justparbox` to be the vehicle by which the justification of the surrounding environment is examined and set for the `\parbox`.

The limitation would be that it can't be used where `\rightskip` is otherwise altered, for example, inside some list environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\xdef\justcase{\the\parfillskip,\the\rightskip}
{\raggedright\xdef\ragrcase{\the\parfillskip,\the\rightskip}}
{\raggedleft\xdef\raglcase{\the\parfillskip,\the\rightskip}}
{\centering\xdef\cencase{\the\parfillskip,\the\rightskip}}
\newcommand\justparbox[3][c]{\xdef\tmp{\the\parfillskip,\the\rightskip}%
  \ifx\tmp\ragrcase\parbox[#1]{#2}{\raggedright#3}\else
  \ifx\tmp\raglcase\parbox[#1]{#2}{\raggedleft#3}\else
  \ifx\tmp\cencase\parbox[#1]{#2}{\centering#3}\else
    \parbox[#1]{#2}{#3}\fi\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
\meaning\centering

\meaning\raggedright

\meaning\raggedleft

\hrulefill

\newcommand\mydata{\lipsum[4]\par\justparbox[t]{5in}{\lipsum[4]}%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill\par}

\mydata
{\raggedright\mydata}
{\raggedleft\mydata}
{\centering\mydata}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So far it worked fine within a tabular environment. However, I just found out that it doesn't within tabularx. To fix it, the \leftskip length must be used instead of \parfillskip.

Comment: @e_moro Thanks for that updated information.

Answer (score 2):

TeX has no `\ifskip` comparator, but we can emulate it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\equalskipTF}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\the\glueexpr#1\relax}{\the\glueexpr#2}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\testrlcenrr}{%
  \equalskipTF{\rightskip}{\@flushglue}%
    {% either center or raggedright
     \equalskipTF{\leftskip}{\@flushglue}%
      {% center
       \let\rl@cen@rr\centering
      }%
      {% raggedright
       \let\rl@cen@rr\raggedright
      }%
    }%
    {% either raggedleft or justified
     \equalskipTF{\leftskip}{\@flushglue}
      {% raggedleft
       \let\rl@cen@rr\raggedleft
      }
      {% justified
       \let\rl@cen@rr\relax
      }%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\pparbox}[3][c]{%
   \testrlcenrr
   \parbox[#1]{#2}{\rl@cen@rr#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Normal text}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\bigskip

\noindent
\pparbox{10cm}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

\section{Ragged right}

\begin{flushleft}
\lipsum[2][1-3]    

\bigskip

\pparbox{10cm}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
\end{flushleft}

\section{Center}

\begin{center}
\lipsum[2][1-3]    

\bigskip

\pparbox{10cm}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
\end{center}

\section{Ragged left}

\begin{flushright}
\lipsum[2][1-3]    

\bigskip

\pparbox{10cm}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation.

1. `\centering` has both `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` set to `\@flushglue`
2. `\raggedright` has zero leftskip and `\rightskip=\@flushglue`
3. `\raggedleft` has zero rightskip and `\leftskip=\@flushglue`

Comment: The same comment as the another answer: It works fine into a tabular environment. And also a clear explanation. I would like to select both answers. I simply choose the first one.